# Can we use XML and Jquery to sort links by their number (id)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I've tried to sort links I've got in a XML file. I've using AJAX from jquery but I have problems.
I wanted to create links order by their number into panels that can slide.
Panels can slide but I'm a beginner using Jquery and Javascript and i don't know how I can do using AJAX to import my XML and sort it.
But wait there's more ! In my XML I have a "commen" section that I wanted to show in "commentaire" section on my HTML every time mouse come over a link...
I know it's a little bit complicated for a beginner, and my skills in english are not great to explicated what i wanted to do.
There's my code :

```
<HTML>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>index intuitif</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id = "tableau" border =1>
         <td>
            <div class="toggle-info" onClick=theme1()>
               <h1>Theme 1 </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="info-panel">
               <ul id = "theme1">
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(1)> Lien 1 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(2)> Lien 2 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(3)> Lien 3 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(4)> Lien 4 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(5)> Lien 5 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(6)> Lien 6 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(7)> Lien 7 </a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="toggle-info">
               <h1>Theme 2 </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="info-panel" onClick=theme2()>
               <ul id = "theme2">
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(1)> Lien 1 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(2)> Lien 2 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(3)> Lien 3 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(4)> Lien 4 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(5)> Lien 5 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(6)> Lien 6 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(7)> Lien 7 </a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="toggle-info">
               <h1>Theme3</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="info-panel" onClick=theme3()>
               <ul id= "theme3">
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(1)> Lien 1 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(2)> Lien 2 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(3)> Lien 3 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(4)> Lien 4 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(5)> Lien 5 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(6)> Lien 6 </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href= "" onMouseOver=displayBD(7)> Lien 7 </a> </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </td>
      </table>
      <div id="commentaire">
         Bonsoir
      </div>
      <script>
         var nbr_lignes = document.getElementById('tableau').rows.length;
         var nbr_colonnes = document.getElementById('tableau').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length;
         var nbr_colonnes = document.getElementById('tableau').rows[0].cells.length;
         var themeSelect ;
         var i  =  0 ;
         var ndecs;
         var contenu=" ";
         var results = new Array ;
         var descrithem1= new Array;
         var descrithem2= new Array;
         var descrithem3= new Array; 
         var length1 = $('#theme1 > *').length;
         var length2 = $('#theme2 > *').length;
         var length3 = $('#theme3 > *').length;
         var lengthmax1= length1;
         var lengthmax2= length2;
         var lengthmax3= length3;
         var themeSelect;
         var commentaira;
         var $xml= $.parseXML('<bds> <serie1 id="1"> <desc> <num> 2 </num><title>we are on 1 </title><commen>HI </commen><URL>Idk</URL></desc><desc><num> 1 </num><title>we are on  2 </title><commen>Hello world </commen><URL>Baptiste</URL></desc></serie1></bds>')
         /*
            function theme1(){
            themeSelect = 1 ;
            }
            function theme2(){
            themeSelect = 2 ;
            }
            function theme3(){
            themeSelect = 3 ;
            }
             function ajout(){
             var themeajout=prompt("theme to add");
             if (themeajout==1)
             {
             ndecs = prompt ("new description");
             descrithem1.push(ndecs);

             }
             if (themeajout==2)
             {
             ndecs = prompt ("new description");
             descrithem2.push(ndecs);
             }
             if (themeajout==3)
             {
             ndecs = prompt ("new description");
             descrithem3.push(ndecs);
             }
             }
             function affichage ()
             {   
             var div = document.getElementById("commentaire");
                 div.textContent = descri[i];
                 var text = div.textContent;
             }
             */

             /*
             function ajoutLien(){
             var numtheme = prompt("numero de votre theme");
             if (numtheme == 1)
             {
             lengthmax1= lengthmax1 +1 ;
             document.getElementById('theme1').innerHTML += "<li> <a href= \"\" id=\"3-1\" onMouseOver=Lien(1)> Lien " + lengthmax1 +" </a> </li>";
             }
             if (numtheme == 2)
             {
             lengthmax2= lengthmax2 +1 ;
             document.getElementById('theme2').innerHTML += "<li> <a href= \"\" id=\"3-1\" onMouseOver=Lien(1)> Lien " + lengthmax2 +" </a> </li>";
             }
             if (numtheme == 3)
             {
             lengthmax3= lengthmax3 +1 ;
             document.getElementById('theme3').innerHTML += "<li> <a href= \"\" id=\"3-1\" onMouseOver=Lien(1)> Lien " + lengthmax3 +" </a> </li>";
             }
             }
*/
             $(function() {
             $(".toggle-info").on("click", function() {
             if($(this).next(".info-panel").attr('style') == 'display: block;'){
             $(this).next(".info-panel").slideUp(200);
             } else {
             $(".info-panel").each(function(){
             $(this).slideUp(200);
             });
             $(this).next(".info-panel").slideToggle(200);
             }   
             });
             $(".info-panel").on("click", function() {
             $(this).slideUp(200);
             });
             });
$(document).ready(  
function()
 {$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "text.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml)
                     {
                       $(xml).find('bds').each(  
                         function()
                         {
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                            alert (id);
                            $(this).find('desc').each(

                                            function()
                                            {

                                                var commen = $(this).find('commen').text();
                                                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                                                var URL = $(this).find('URL').text();
                                            });
                          });
                      }
        });
  }
);
$($xml).find('serie1').each(function() {
var commen = $(this).find('commen').text();
var title = $(this).find('title').text();
var URL = $(this).find('URL').text();
var num = $(this).find('num').text();

    results.push({
        id: $(this).attr('id'),
        num : num,
        commen: commen,
        title: title,
        URL: URL
    });
})
    results.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.num > b.num;
});
    var html=[];
$.each(results, function() {
   html.push('<div>commentaires : ' + this.commen + '</div>')

})
$('body').append( html.join(''))

 function displayBD(inte)
 {
alert(this.results);
if (this.num ==inte)
{commentaira = results.commen;
document.getElementById("commentaire").innerHTML = results.commen;
}

alert(commentaira);
 }

      </script>
      <style type='text/css'>
         .toggle-info {
         cursor: pointer;
         }
         .info-panel {
         display: none;
         cursor: pointer;
         }
         * { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: .95em; }
         fieldset { margin: 15px; padding-left: 1em; padding-right: 1em; padding-bottom: 1em; }
         legend { margin: 10px; }
         #outputBDFieldset { display: none; }
         #nbBD {    font-weight: normal; }
      </style>
   </body>
</HTML>
```

Many functions are here before I'm using Jquery (in commentary).
I'm using the var $xml for testing. But my XML is bigger :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<bds>
        <serie1 id="1">
                <desc>
                        <num> 1 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 1 </title>
                        <commen>Hello </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 2 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 2 </title>
                        <commen>HI </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 3 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 3 </title>
                        <commen>How are you  </commen>
                        <URL>Gars inconnu</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 4 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 4 </title>
                        <commen>Idk  </commen>
                        <URL>Raymond</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 5 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 5 </title>
                        <commen>Thank you </commen>
                        <URL>Eric</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 6 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 6 </title>
                        <commen>You're welcome  </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 7 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 7 </title>
                        <commen>Sorry </commen>
                        <URL>Céline</URL>
                </desc>
        </serie1>
            <serie2 id="2">
                <desc>
                        <num> 1 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 1 </title>
                        <commen>Hello </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 2 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 2 </title>
                        <commen>HI </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 3 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 3 </title>
                        <commen>How are you  </commen>
                        <URL>Gars inconnu</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 4 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 4 </title>
                        <commen>Idk  </commen>
                        <URL>Raymond</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 5 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 5 </title>
                        <commen>Thank you </commen>
                        <URL>Eric</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 6 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 6 </title>
                        <commen>You're welcome  </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 7 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 7 </title>
                        <commen>Sorry </commen>
                        <URL>Céline</URL>
                </desc>
        </serie2>
            <serie3 id="3">
                <desc>
                        <num> 1 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 1 </title>
                        <commen>Hello </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 2 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 2 </title>
                        <commen>HI </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 3 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 3 </title>
                        <commen>How are you  </commen>
                        <URL>Gars inconnu</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 4 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 4 </title>
                        <commen>Idk  </commen>
                        <URL>Raymond</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 5 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 5 </title>
                        <commen>Thank you </commen>
                        <URL>Eric</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 6 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 6 </title>
                        <commen>You're welcome  </commen>
                        <URL>Baptiste</URL>
                </desc>
                <desc>
                        <num> 7 </num>
                        <title>nous sommes sur le lien 7 </title>
                        <commen>Sorry </commen>
                        <URL>Céline</URL>
                </desc>
        </serie3>
</bds>
```

If you have a solution to have and parse XML object to treat the number of links because I wanted to create them according to the number of links in the panels according to the number of links in the XML...
I don't even know if i can do that.
So here's my question : 
Can Jquery modify a XML and save it ?
Can I use it for sort and implement my pannels with  ?
I know this is a little complicated but thank you for your reading.

Comment: Why not convert the XML to JSON? That way you can do whatever you want to it, including converting the results to an array and then sorting it.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that before, but I don't know if I can convert XML -> JSON Then convert it again in XML, I know the best is using PHP but i can't...
   var Theme1=  '{ "Serie1" : [' +
'{ "num":"1" , "title":"Lien1" ,"commen":"Youpi","URL":"Yolo"},' +
'{ "num":"2" , "title":"Lien2" ,"commen":"Youpla","URL":"Yolo2"},' +
'{ "num":"3" , "title":"Lien3" ,"commen":"Yooou","URL":"Yolo3"},']}';
var obj = JSON.parse(Theme1);
document.getElementById("commentaire").innerHTML =
obj.Serie1[1].title + " " + obj.Serie1[1].commen;
But same as Jquery I never used JSON before... I don't if this is possible...

Comment: You don't need to output the XML as JSON, instead [use JS to convert XML to JSON](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json)

Comment: If you already have data in XML, no need to convert it to JSON.  jQuery can search XML content, and sort the results.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
Every time I tried to treat them for the result.sort fonction or in alrt with a parameters, it's a [Object object] value. Even if I tried to parseInt it.
I will try the evolutionxbox idea thank you